# How to go to before last character in a line?

Tags: navigation

I know its a simple one, but I've had no luck finding it so far.

I known A, brings you to the end of a line.

However, I would like to jump to and, insert after the second last character.

Example:
My name is Joh|n

Comment: Please give example test cases.

Comment: `$` goes to the last character, then left cursor. If left cursor doesn't work, then `h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean insert before last character: `$i` (not repeatable like `A`)

If you mean just to go to the second to last character: `$h`

Comment: Thanks D. Ben Knoble! Inserting before the last character is what I was looking for.

Comment: @MarkCosgrave, that is such a... specific requirement.