# How to go to the nth-to-last character in insert mode?

Tags: cursor-movement, insert-mode

Capital `A` in Vim takes me to the last character in insert mode, but can I go to the nth-to-last character in insert mode (or append mode) in vim?

Example:

```
this is some t|ext
```

how to go specifically to the location of the `|` in insert mode, I would imagine something like `<n>+A` where `n` is an integer. I did see a similar question here: [how-to-go-to-before-last-character-in-a-line](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/19291/how-to-go-to-before-last-character-in-a-line) and an answer suggested to use `$i`, to go to the second-to-last character in insert mode, but this can't go to the nth character.

[Edit]:

I only want to end up in insert mode, not necessarily do all the commands in insert mode but rather do them in normal mode.

Comment: that's what normal mode is for ;)

Comment: What if I wanted to go to the middle character in the line?

Comment: Either move with the cursor as in any other ordinary editor, or use normal mode. That's what it is for

Comment: Yeah I get that, what I’m asking is like is there any other way other than just moving repeatedly, to go to the middle character of the line or at least the nth character

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: @an4s911 You can also use `Ctrl+O` from Insert mode to enter a single Normal mode command and stay in Insert mode otherwise. So, for example, you can use `Ctrl+O 20 |` to go to column 20 in the current line (and continue in Insert mode) or `Ctrl+O gM` to go to the middle of the current line. Unfortunately there isn't a single Normal mode command to go to the nth-character before the end of the line, so `Ctrl+O` isn't that helpful then, but if you create a Normal-mode mapping to take the count and go to the nth character before the end, `Ctrl+O` can help you access it.

Comment: @filbranden @Christian as I understand it, OP does not ask to move while in insert mode, but to enter it afterwards as would `A` do.

Comment: @Biggybi Yes you are right. And, @filbranden just for clarification does `Ctrl+O gM` go to the middle of current line?

Comment: @an4s911 Yes `gM` takes you to the middle of the line, see `:help gM`.

Answer (score 2):

I concocted a script that does what you want. I think it handles most corner cases, however you might find some bugs down the road if you decide to use it.

```
function! AWithCount(count) abort
  " default behaviour (no count)
  if !a:count
    "append to end of line, like `A`
    startinsert!
    return
  endif

  " line too short for `count` (`:h col())
  " `col('$')` => length of current line
  if col('$') - 1 < a:count
    " go to first non-whitespace, or to start if only whitespaces
    " -> `normal 0` / `normal _`
    " `:h =~` `:h trinary`
    normal (getline('.') =~ "^\\s\\+$") ? "0" : "_"
    startinsert
    return
  endif

  " place cursor and enter insert mode
  " -> `$X<left><right>`, X a number
  " `:h :exe`
  exe "normal $" . a:count . "\<left>\<right>"
  startinsert
endfunction

" `:h <silent>` to avoid clutter in the command line
" <c-u> to clear things vim puts in command line
nnoremap <silent> A :<c-u>call AWithCount(v:count)<cr>
```

Comment: Thats really amazing. Could u please explain the code as well. The syntax is not that intuitively understandable

Comment: @an4s911 Vimscript can indeed turn out to be pretty cryptic. I added some comments to better explain the code, as well as help topics you may want to check out. This should clarify things a whole lot.

Answer (score 1):

`<ALT-$> [count] hi` where `[count]` is a number

1. the Alt key to enter commands while in insert mode
2. while pressing the Alt key press "$" to go to end of line
3. press [count] "h" to go left [count] times
4. press i  to go into insert mode

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I'm not sure your answer is actually addressing the question. One part of the question is about moving while in Insert mode, while your answer seems to include Normal mode commands only... Your answer was also flagged due to being too short, make sure you further explain what the commands are doing, why they're needed, etc.

Comment: @fibrandon edited

Comment: @filbranden by ‘in insert mode’ I actually meant doing the commands in normal mode and then finally ending up in insert.